# Keras Transfer Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

Let's say that I wanted to train a ConvNet to tell me if in a photo it is raining or not, how will the procedures be?

Given that I have two train variables, `trainX` and `trainY`, the `trainX` will be the photo and `trainY` will be the labels (e.g. `rain` or `no-rain`).

The goal of the network is to output the "right" answer. The question is: *do I just need to run the `model.predict()` function and expect valid results?*

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: first, you need to create the model structure and then fit it on your data. then only you can do model.predict()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Build your CNN Model: Layers, Activation-Functions...

2) Train it with your existing `trainX` and `trainY`-Dataset. (use Augmentation to get better results in the end)

3) Validate with another Dataset, lets say they are called: `testX` and `testY`

4) Modify the settings of your Model until your accuracy and loss are high enough for what you need them...

5) enjoy your CNN

This could help you on your way:
[Building a CNN with Keras](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-convolutional-neural-network-cnn-in-keras-329fbbadc5f5)

Comment: Two things: by "settings" you mean like the batch size, momentum? For the X and Y am I right though? X is photos and Y is labels?

Comment: With X and Y you are right, X is photos and Y is labels...
But by Settings, I would focus on modifying the Model itself. adding new layers, getting rid of unnecessary layers, changing kernel-size, padding,dropout-rate, the number of filters...all the parameters you have to enter when you are building your own CNN. There is no 'right' amount of kernels or layers... it's more like trial and error...Batch-Size and Momentum are also variable and you can keep an eye on them, but optimization usually starts way earlier